# Column name changes in R for loop for defined data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have defined a blank data frame with the column name for calculation. When I use the data frame in for loop to bind the rows in data frame the column name gets change. How can I retain the column name intact.

I am using the below code.

```
res <- data.frame(Calculations = integer())
for (i in 1:3) {
  calc <- i * runif(1)
  res <- rbind(res, calc)
}
print(res)
```

Result I get from this code is

```
print(res)
  X0.890447217039764
1          0.8904472
2          1.9034397
3          1.8227991
```

Whereas I am expecting

```
print(res)
  Calculations
1          0.8904472
2          1.9034397
3          1.8227991
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to add values to a column in a loop ?

If you are creating a new dataframe you can do

```
data.frame(Calculations = runif(3))
```

Or if the dataframe is already existing, you can add a new column to it by doing

```
df$Calculations <- runif(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  calc <- i * runif(1)
  res <- rbind(res, list(Calculations=calc))
}
```

Another possibility is to rename after the loop:

```
colnames(res) <- "Calculations"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can predefine number of rows for the blank *data.frame*, then assign each row using a *forloop*:

```
res <- data.frame(Calculations = integer(length = 3))

for (i in 1:3) {
  res[i , "Calculations"] <- i * runif(1)
}
```

---

Note:

- defining as integer, then assigning floating points, maybe use `numeric(length = 3)` instead
- I assume your real calculations are more complex than this, otherwise there are better **R** way of doing things, for example @Ronak's answer.
- Growing objects in a *forloop* is not advised. `res <- rbind(res, calc)`